# inputing data into python tkinter scrolledtreeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I designed a GUI on Python Tkinter using page GUI application. I keep getting an error each time I try to add data from my entry box into the scrolledtreeview:

## insert_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

in button3 i called the function out through command which seems to work but it cant link to the function... and i dont really know what to do to get it working... please my gui also has another solarapp_support.py... i dont know how to add that too... that why i posted a link incase u need that... the two files where generated using the gui app page

```
import sys

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import RECENT11_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = Tk()
    RECENT11_support.set_Tk_var()
    top = SOLAR_APP (root)
    RECENT11_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_SOLAR_APP(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = Toplevel (root)
    RECENT11_support.set_Tk_var()
    top = SOLAR_APP (w)
    RECENT11_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_SOLAR_APP():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None


class SOLAR_APP:
       def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        font11 = "-family {Book Antiqua} -size 12 -weight bold -slant "  \
            "roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0"
        font12 = "-family {Segoe UI} -size 9 -weight bold -slant roman"  \
            " -underline 0 -overstrike 0"
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        top.geometry("596x478+403+138")
        top.title("SOLAR APP")
        top.configure(relief="ridge")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        def insert_data(self):
            self.Scrolledtreeview1.insert('self.TNotebook1_t0', 'end', text=str(self.i),
                                          values=(
                                              self.Entry1.get(), self.Entry2.get(), self.Entry3.get(),
                                              self.Entry4.get()))
            # Increment counter
            self.i = self.i + 1

        self.Button1 = Button(top)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.86, rely=0.69, height=34, width=67)
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''FINISH''')

        self.Button2 = Button(top)
        self.Button2.place(relx=0.86, rely=0.88, height=34, width=67)
        self.Button2.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button2.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button2.configure(text='''PRINT''')

        self.style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.map('TNotebook.Tab', background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])
        self.TNotebook1 = ttk.Notebook(top)
        self.TNotebook1.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.0, relheight=0.95, relwidth=0.82)

        self.TNotebook1.configure(width=486)
        self.TNotebook1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TNotebook1_t0 = Frame(self.TNotebook1)
        self.TNotebook1.add(self.TNotebook1_t0, padding=3)
        self.TNotebook1.tab(0, text="LOAD SETUP", compound="none", underline="-1"
                ,)
        self.TNotebook1_t0.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t0.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t0.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.TNotebook1_t1 = Frame(self.TNotebook1)
        self.TNotebook1.add(self.TNotebook1_t1, padding=3)
        self.TNotebook1.tab(1, text="BATTERY SETUP", compound="left"
                ,underline="-1", )
        self.TNotebook1_t1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.TNotebook1_t2 = Frame(self.TNotebook1)
        self.TNotebook1.add(self.TNotebook1_t2, padding=3)
        self.TNotebook1.tab(2, text="PANEL SETUP", compound="none", underline="-1"
                ,)
        self.TNotebook1_t2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.TNotebook1_t3 = Frame(self.TNotebook1)
        self.TNotebook1.add(self.TNotebook1_t3, padding=3)
        self.TNotebook1.tab(3, text="INVERTER SETUP", compound="none"
                ,underline="-1", )
        self.TNotebook1_t3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook1_t3.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.Entry1 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Entry1.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.07,height=30, relwidth=0.22)
        self.Entry1.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry1.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry1.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.Entry2 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Entry2.place(relx=0.27, rely=0.07,height=30, relwidth=0.13)
        self.Entry2.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry2.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry2.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry2.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry2.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.Entry3 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Entry3.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.07,height=30, relwidth=0.11)
        self.Entry3.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry3.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry3.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry3.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry3.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.Entry4 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Entry4.place(relx=0.61, rely=0.07,height=30, relwidth=0.09)
        self.Entry4.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry4.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry4.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry4.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry4.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry4.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry4.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry4.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry4.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.Label1 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.17, height=21, width=44)
        self.Label1.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label1.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''ITEM''')

        self.Label2 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Label2.place(relx=0.27, rely=0.17, height=21, width=61)
        self.Label2.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label2.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label2.configure(text='''WATTAGE''')

        self.Label3 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Label3.place(relx=0.46, rely=0.17, height=21, width=29)
        self.Label3.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label3.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label3.configure(text='''QTY''')

        self.Label4 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Label4.place(relx=0.61, rely=0.17, height=21, width=53)
        self.Label4.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label4.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label4.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label4.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label4.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label4.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label4.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label4.configure(text='''HOUR(S)''')

        self.style.configure('Treeview.Heading',  font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1 = ScrolledTreeView(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.31, relheight=0.7
                , relwidth=1.0)
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.configure(columns="Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("#0",text="S/N")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("#0",anchor="center")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("#0",width="35")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("#0",minwidth="20")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("#0",stretch="1")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("#0",anchor="w")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col1",text="ITEM")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col1",anchor="center")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col1",width="180")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col1",minwidth="20")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col1",stretch="1")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col1",anchor="w")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col2",text="WATTAGE")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col2",anchor="center")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col2",width="90")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col2",minwidth="20")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col2",stretch="1")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col2",anchor="w")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col3",text="QTY")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col3",anchor="center")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col3",width="40")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col3",minwidth="20")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col3",stretch="1")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col3",anchor="w")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col4",text="HOUR(s)")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.heading("Col4",anchor="center")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col4",width="90")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col4",minwidth="20")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col4",stretch="1")
        self.Scrolledtreeview1.column("Col4",anchor="w")
        self.i = 0


        self.Button3 = Button(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Button3.place(relx=0.82, rely=0.02, height=44, width=77)
        self.Button3.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button3.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button3.configure(command=insert_data)
        self.Button3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button3.configure(font=font11)
        self.Button3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button3.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button3.configure(text='''ADD''')

        self.Button4 = Button(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Button4.place(relx=0.88, rely=0.17, height=34, width=47)
        self.Button4.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button4.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button4.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button4.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button4.configure(font=font12)
        self.Button4.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button4.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button4.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button4.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button4.configure(text='''DELETE''')

        self.Label9 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Label9.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.12, height=21, width=128)
        self.Label9.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label9.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label9.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label9.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label9.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label9.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label9.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label9.configure(text='''BATTERY RATING (AH)''')

        self.Label10 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Label10.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.24, height=21, width=124)
        self.Label10.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label10.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label10.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label10.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label10.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label10.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label10.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label10.configure(text='''BATTERY VOLTAGE(V)''')

        self.Label11 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Label11.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.35, height=21, width=124)
        self.Label11.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label11.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label11.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label11.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label11.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label11.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label11.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label11.configure(text='''DAYS OF AUTONOMY''')

        self.Label12 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Label12.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.47, height=21, width=103)
        self.Label12.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label12.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label12.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label12.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label12.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label12.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label12.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label12.configure(text='''DISCHARGE LEVEL''')

        self.Entry8 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Entry8.place(relx=0.36, rely=0.12,height=20, relwidth=0.34)
        self.Entry8.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry8.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry8.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry8.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry8.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry8.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry8.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry8.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry8.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.Entry9 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Entry9.place(relx=0.36, rely=0.24,height=20, relwidth=0.34)
        self.Entry9.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry9.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry9.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry9.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry9.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry9.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry9.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry9.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry9.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.Entry10 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Entry10.place(relx=0.36, rely=0.35,height=20, relwidth=0.34)
        self.Entry10.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry10.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry10.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry10.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry10.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry10.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry10.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry10.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry10.configure(selectforeground="black")

        self.Spinbox1 = Spinbox(self.TNotebook1_t1, from_=50.0, to=80.0)
        self.Spinbox1.place(relx=0.36, rely=0.47, relheight=0.04, relwidth=0.09)
        self.Spinbox1.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(background="white")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(buttonbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(from_="50.0")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(highlightbackground="black")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(increment="15.0")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(textvariable=RECENT11_support.spinbox)
        self.Spinbox1.configure(to="80.0")
        self.Spinbox1.configure(width=5)
        self.Spinbox1.configure(wrap=1)

        self.Label13 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t1)
        self.Label13.place(relx=0.46, rely=0.47, height=21, width=16)
        self.Label13.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label13.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label13.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label13.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label13.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label13.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label13.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label13.configure(text='''%''')

        self.Label14 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t2)
        self.Label14.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.21, height=21, width=87)
        self.Label14.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label14.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label14.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label14.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label14.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label14.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label14.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label14.configure(text='''PANEL RATING''')

        self.Label15 = Label(self.TNotebook1_t2)
        self.Label15.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.31, height=21, width=96)
        self.Label15.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label15.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label15.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label15.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label15.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label15.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label15.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label15.configure(text='''PANEL VOLTAGE''')

        self.Entry11 = Entry(self.TNotebook1_t2)
        self.Entry11.place(relx=0.44, rely=0.21,height=20, relwidth=0.34)
        self.Entry11.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry11.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry11.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry11.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry11.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Entry11.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Entry11.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry11.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Entry11.configure(selectforeground="black")




# The following code is added to facilitate the Scrolled widgets you specified.
class AutoScroll(object):
    '''Configure the scrollbars for a widget.'''

    def __init__(self, master):
        #  Rozen. Added the try-except clauses so that this class
        #  could be used for scrolled entry widget for which vertical
        #  scrolling is not supported. 5/7/14.
        try:
            vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient='vertical', command=self.yview)
        except:
            pass
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient='horizontal', command=self.xview)

        #self.configure(yscrollcommand=_autoscroll(vsb),
        #    xscrollcommand=_autoscroll(hsb))
        try:
            self.configure(yscrollcommand=self._autoscroll(vsb))
        except:
            pass
        self.configure(xscrollcommand=self._autoscroll(hsb))

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
        try:
            vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')
        except:
            pass
        hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

        master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Copy geometry methods of master  (taken from ScrolledText.py)
        if py3:
            methods = Pack.__dict__.keys() | Grid.__dict__.keys() \
                  | Place.__dict__.keys()
        else:
            methods = Pack.__dict__.keys() + Grid.__dict__.keys() \
                  + Place.__dict__.keys()

        for meth in methods:
            if meth[0] != '_' and meth not in ('config', 'configure'):
                setattr(self, meth, getattr(master, meth))

    @staticmethod
    def _autoscroll(sbar):
        '''Hide and show scrollbar as needed.'''
        def wrapped(first, last):
            first, last = float(first), float(last)
            if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
                sbar.grid_remove()
            else:
                sbar.grid()
            sbar.set(first, last)
        return wrapped

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.master)

def _create_container(func):
    '''Creates a ttk Frame with a given master, and use this new frame to
    place the scrollbars and the widget.'''
    def wrapped(cls, master, **kw):
        container = ttk.Frame(master)
        return func(cls, container, **kw)
    return wrapped

class ScrolledTreeView(AutoScroll, ttk.Treeview):
    '''A standard ttk Treeview widget with scrollbars that will
    automatically show/hide as needed.'''
    @_create_container
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        AutoScroll.__init__(self, master)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: Please don't post your code in a link in the comment section. You need to edit your post and add your current code so we can easily help you!

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Well you have not given us enough code to test your problem but judging by your error and the little code you have provided you are using a class method and you have not called `insert_data()` using the self prefix. try using `self.insert_data()` instead.

Comment: MIKE thanks for your positive input.. ive tried it but couldnt figure how to get it to work... please i would really appreciate your help. wish u could look at my link and check  my code out... would really appreciate... im super new to coding and python.. need your support please

Comment: hello please ive edited my question and added the main body of the code... please can someone help me solve my problem

Comment: @Mike-SMT please can u help me.... sorry bugging you but im really lost of any new ideas... current tweaked it to stop showing errors but the tree view is not displaying the info when the button is pressed... wish we could talk one on one

Comment: It appears to be your command in Button3 that is wrong here. `self.Button3.configure(command=insert_data)` should be `self.Button3.configure(command=self.insert_data)`. Also your code (too much code btw) cannot be tested as we do not have your import `RECENT11_support`. Please take the time to do a MCVE if the `Button3` correction is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues here. It is not possible to test your code due to us not knowing what is in `RECENT11_support`. Without this your code is not possible to start. I can see that `Button3` has an invalid command.

```
self.Button3.configure(command=insert_data)
```

Should be:

```
self.Button3.configure(command=self.insert_data)
```

That said you do not need to config each option in a widget on a separate line. That is just way 2 much code. You can do all of it on one line.

For example this:

```
self.Button1 = Button(top)
self.Button1.place(relx=0.86, rely=0.69, height=34, width=67)
self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
self.Button1.configure(text='''FINISH''')
```

Should look something like this:

```
self.Button1 = Button(top, text='''FINISH''', activebackground="#d9d9d9", activeforeground="#000000",
                      background="#d9d9d9", disabledforeground="#a3a3a3", disabledforeground="#a3a3a3",
                      foreground="#000000", highlightbackground="#d9d9d9", highlightcolor="black")
self.Button1.place(relx=0.86, rely=0.69, height=34, width=67)
```

To be honest thought if you are using a GUI generator then I am not sure we can help you.
If you do not know how the code works or cannot read it on your own then you may not be able to fix it. Any changes you make with your GUI generator will probably cause the same break to occur.

Your GUI generator is also using things like `place()` where it is not really needed in most applications for simple placement of widgets. I think you will be better off learning how to build the GUI yourself in code otherwise we wont be able to really help you with your problem.